# Getting The Most Recent Data Item - Google App Engine - Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I need to retrieve the most recent item added to a collection. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
class Box(db.Model):
    ID = db.IntegerProperty()

class Item(db.Model):
    box = db.ReferenceProperty(Action, collection_name='items')
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

#get most recent item
lastItem = box.items.order('-date')[0]
```

Is this an expensive way to do it? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to iterate over a list of boxes, that is a very bad way to do it.  You will run an additional query for every box.  You can easily see what is going on with [Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html).

If you are doing one of those per request, it may be ok.  But it is not ideal.  you might also want to use:  `lastItem = box.items.order('-date').get()`.  [get](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_get) will only return the first result to the app.

If possible it would be significantly faster to add a `lastItem` property to `Box`, or store the `Box ID` (*your attribute*) on `Item`.  In other words, denormalize the data.  If you are going to fetch a list of Boxes and their most recent item you **need** to use this type of approach.

Comment: Perfect. I added a lastItem property to Box which will update every time I add an item to Box. That is much better. Thank you.