# GAE - retrieving the last entry (python)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to get the most recent data item from the datastore.
I am trying to apply the method as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981997/getting-the-most-recent-data-item-google-app-engine-python) but I am getting the object `<__main__.Rep object at 0x075F1730>` not the item. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

The Model is:

```
class Rep(db.Model):
    sent = db.StringProperty()
    time = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is the handler:

```
class Repeater(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):        
        reps = Rep()
        reps.sent = self.request.get('sentence')
        reps.put()

        s = self.request.get('sentence')             

        query = reps.all()
        last = query.order('-time').get()
        sentences = query
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong at all.

`<__main__.Rep object at 0x075F1730>` is presumably an instance of your Rep class, as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem is I want to compare "s" -the item entered- to the last item in the datastore "last". But this does not work because "last" is the object and "s" is a string. Does this make sense?

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you explain why "last" is the object but "last.sent" is a string. I am confused about this.

Comment: Rep is a class, last is an instance of the class, and sent is a method. You can find explanations of each concept @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_concepts_and_features